# Mutually inverse functions based on the two real branches of the Lambert W function

Tags: integration, reference-request, inverse-function, lambert-w

$\require{begingroup} \begingroup$
$\def\e{\mathrm{e}}\def\W{\operatorname{W}}\def\Wp{\operatorname{W_0}}\def\Wm{\operatorname{W_{-1}}}$

Let
\begin{align}
f_0(x)&=-\Wp(-\tfrac1x\,\exp(-\tfrac1x))
\tag{1}\label{1}
,\\
f_1(x)&=-\frac{1}{\Wm(-x\,\exp(-x))}
\tag{2}\label{2}
,\quad x\in(0,1)
.
\end{align}

Then
\begin{align}
f_1(f_0(x))&=x
\tag{3}\label{3}
,\\
f_0(f_1(x))&=x
\tag{4}\label{4}
.
\end{align}

Note that
for $x\in(0,1)$

\begin{align}
\Wp(-\tfrac1x\,\exp(-\tfrac1x))
\ne -\tfrac1x
\tag{5}\label{5}
,\\
\Wm(-x\,\exp(-x))
\ne -x
\tag{6}\label{6}
.
\end{align}

Here is a graph:

[image]

The area under the curve $f_1(x)$ is

\begin{align}
\int_0^1 f_1(x)\,dx &=\gamma
\approx 0.5772156649
,
\end{align}

hence the area bounded by
$f_0(x)$ and $f_1(x)$ is $2\gamma-1$.

**Question:** is there known references where these
mutually inverse functions were used?

$\endgroup$